# how to see kube-scheduler log?

Tags: kubernetes

I also want to see the logs of kube-scheduler go files. I tried different methods like

- using kubeclt logs: this show the event logs of kube-scheduler but not all the logs in kube-scheduler.
- using docker logs [kube-scheduler container id]: it does not have any log.
- journalctl -u kubelet: only show the log of kubelet.

All of these do not work. Please let me know if you guys found the way to log them out.

Answer (score 3):

Check this on Master `/var/log/kube-scheduler.log`

see also:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-cluster/

Comment: How does one get to the master?`kubectl cluster-info` returns the IP address but then what?

Comment: @Tilo please explain what you mean by "Master". Is this a node? Or a pod? If so, how can you find it?

Comment: @BenDavis It is the master node. You could try this to find it: `kubectl get node --selector='node-role.kubernetes.io/master'`

Comment: @steinybot if you have the pod name you could try running this command `kubectl exec --stdin --tty $POD_NAME -- /bin/bash` to access the logs.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the verbosity level of kube-scheduler by going into config yaml file and add an argument `--v N`. I find 4 works for me. It will be showing logs for various scheduler go files.  Then you can check `kubectl logs` for a specific kube-scheduler pod.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-scheduler/

Comment: Where can you fnd this yaml file?

Answer (score 1):

I use `kubectl get events` for this.